# Horizontal scrolling of sticky header doesn't working

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling, sticky

I have a sticky header on my page, but I found a bug that buttons on right side of sticky header is not visible when browser window is small... and horizontal scrolling does not work for hearder.

Here is html code:

```
<div class="search-container">
   <div class="sticky-wrapper">
     <!-- it's fixed header -->
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
     <!-- search filters e.g. -->
   </div>
   <div class="content">
     <!-- search results e.g. -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS (sass) code:

```
.search-container {

  .sticky-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 #8f8f8f;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 229px;
  }

  .content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border-top: 4px solid #5d5d5d;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 691px !important;
  }
}
```

When I make browser window smaller then (sidebar + content) width, horizontal scrolling appears - but it works only for .sidebar and .content.

How can I make sticky header horizontal-scrollable too?

P.S. it's important to working in FF, Chrome, IE >= 9. And I it not good to change/add new css ids or classes, cause many tests become broken.

Please, help.
Thanks kindly.

If it will be helpful - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afs5k1zp/) with header and content

Comment: Can you put that into jsfiddle? That would make things easier for others.

Comment: on your header you will need `width: 100%;` specifically the `.sticky-wrapper` class

Comment: Yes, since you have set `width:900px;`, the header will obviously be 900px wide and exceed the viewport's width. Since you have it as `position:fixed;`, its position is relative to the viewport so scrolling wouldn't have any effects on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CSS alone cannot handle this scenario. It would be better if you add a pinch of JS flavour. Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afs5k1zp/2/).

Added a JS code: (Note: I have used JQuery, you can also have it rewritten in pure JS if required)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var max_width = 990;   
  if ($(window).width() < max_width) {
    $('.sticky-wrapper').css('margin-left', -$(this).scrollLeft() + "px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For what I could test, and for previous experience, is to add a div inside with a width bigger than the container one, and to that container add an `overflow-x: auto;`

For example:

```
<div class="sticky-wrapper">
    <div class="bigger">Your text here</div>
</div>

.sticky-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 #8f8f8f;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: grey;
    width: 900px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.bigger {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afs5k1zp/1/